# Elixir Undefined function

Tags: elixir

Elixir beginner here. I am attempting to run a hello world elixir script from the iex

The script is a basic hello world example

```
IO.puts "Hello World!"
```

I run the following command from iex

```
iex(1)> elixir hello.exs
```

and get this error:

```
** (CompileError) iex:1: undefined function elixir/1
```

Not sure why I am getting an error, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should run `elixir hello.exs` from the shell, not inside `iex`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just so the answer is not buried in a comment:

> You should run `elixir hello.exs` from the shell, not inside `iex`

Answer (score 2):

I'm also new to Elixir and couldn't figure out why I was receiving "undefined function error" when trying to invoke my "create_deck" example function after having typed `iex -S mix` from the `cards` directory.  Turns out, I was not including the module name when trying to invoke from the interactive shell.  I was supposed to type `Cards.create_deck()`, rather than just `create_deck`.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are in your console.

```
$ elixir hello.exs
```

see: [Running scripts for elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/introduction.html#running-scripts)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24823177)

Comment: Thanks @ManojChoudhari noted on this one.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer rightly suggest, there is no "elixir" function in the interactive elixir shell (iex), so what you meant to do was to execute the elixir command from your system shell.

But, there are helpers in iex that can load files from the directory iex was started in—first a bit of setup, given we have a `test.exs` file in our current working directory with the following contents:

```
defmodule Test do
  def greet(person) do
    "Hi, #{person}!"
  end
end
```

We could load that into our iex session by using the `c/1` (compile file) helper from iex:

```
$ iex
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.5.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Interactive Elixir (1.9.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> c("test.exs")
[Test]
iex(2)> Test.greet("Pau")
"Hi, Pau!"
iex(3)>
```

Other helpers in iex that might help you here is `pwd` that will print the working directory, and `ls` that will list the files in the current working directory—you can change the working directory by using the `cd` helper, that takes a directory as a sting as an argument.